# How do I insert records that have int fields with no values?

Tags: sql, vb.net, ms-access

Let's say I have this Access table with one text field and 4 number fields. Here is the relevant code:

```
Dim cmd As New OleDb.OleDbCommand
    cmd.Connection = con
    cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
    cmd.CommandText = "insert into Table1" _
    & " values(?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@a", a.Text)
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", CInt(b.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@c", CInt(c.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@d", CInt(d.Text))
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@e", CInt(e.Text))

    ole.InsertCommand = cmd
    ole.InsertCommand.ExecuteNonQuery()
    ds.Clear()
    ole.Fill(ds)
```

It works fine at first, but when I leave a number field with no value, it gives this: "Data type mismatch in criteria expression". How do I work around this?

Comment: Are the fields in Table1 nullable? If so you could use DBNull.Value to represent empty fields

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You shouldn't need to convert the value to an integer. That said, using the below function should work.
Use it like this:
cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@b", ValueOrNull(b.Text))

```
Public Function ValueOrNull(ByVal obJ As Object) As Object
    If obJ Is Nothing OrElse obJ Is DBNull.Value OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(obJ.ToString) Then
        Return DBNull.Value
    Else
        Return obJ
    End If
End Function
```